# JQuery mobile - fixed Content size

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use Jquery mobile for a desktop Web application.

I have a page with a fixed header and footer, and when I load the page, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2M5Jc/).

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>Content</p>
        ...
</div>
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to disable the scrollbar and the collapse/expand of the content when I click on the content to always have fixed header and footer...

Comment: Add data-tap-toggle="false" to your fixed header and footer to stop the collapse/expand on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it little bit different.

There's one great jQuery/jQuery Mobile plugin that provides inner content scrolling without affecting parent elements. It is called iScroll and jQuery Mobile extension is called iScrollView.

Take a look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinaglv/touchTouch/master/assets/touchTouch/touchTouch.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" />

        <style>
            .ui-content {
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            .ui-listview {
                margin: 0 !important;
            }

            .example-wrapper, .example-wrapper div.iscroll-scroller {
                width: 100% !important;
            }       
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinaglv/touchTouch/master/assets/touchTouch/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/iscroll.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://example.gajotres.net/iscrollview/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>     
         <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>  
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>     
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>
                        <p>Content</p>                     
                    </ul>
                </div>          
            </div>

            <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately jsFiddle iFrames don't work well with iScroll so I can't provide you with working example. Thou you can directly copy my code and test it locally. Read more about them **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/using-iscroll-with-jquery-mobile/)**.

If you want to prevent header/footer hiding switch to jQuery Mobile 1.3 + or add attribute **data-tap-toggle="false"** to your header/footer div.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I'll look at this plugin. But In fact I have an other problem. I first have a webpage with only a data-role="page" inside. At some point, I load the header, content and footer inside the page with an ajax call : "$("#home").html(data).enhanceWithin();". But event if the content is empty, its height (set to 100%) is bigger than it should (I can scroll)... like if it took the height of the header and the footer...

Comment: Why don't you open a new question and we will solve this for you.

Comment: Ok I'll do it. Thanks